# Авторизация и аутентификация пользователей

Tags: winforms, авторизация

Добрый, день пишу Windows приложение для школы! Как можно сделать авторизацию? например есть три пользователя админ, юсер(учителя) и простые родители и ученики!Как сделать что бы каждый мог заходить под своим логином и паролем?

Comment: А где Вы храните БД пользователей?

Comment: Базы данных нет пока! вообще ни какой! но будит храниться на компьютере! Можно не создавать БД может есть какие то библиотеки или фраемверки?

Comment: Библиотеки чего? Пользователей? Вам необходимо где-то централизовано хранить либо самих пользователей, либо их роли. Например, если ПК будут в домене, то можно использовать доменные учетные записи, однако всё равно придется в серверной БД хранить, кто из них админ, а кто просто ученик.

Comment: А родители с учениками как пользоваться Вашей программой будут? У себя дома ее устанавливать будут, или только в школе?

Comment: ну планирую что бы потом базу использовать на ASP. перезалить и сделать веб сервис! но это в далеком будущем!

Comment: Я имею ввиду библиотека которая работала бы с учетными записями! Я слышал про membership API а как с ней работать таки не понял и вообще можно ли на ней работать в WinForms? А базу я так понял по любому нужно создавать отдельную для этого дела?

Comment: Тогда лучше сразу веб-приложение писать. А его базу использовать и для Windows приложения (ну или наоборот). В общем, нужно определиться, как будете хранить пользователей (хранить их в базе, доменные учетки или может логины из соц.сетей), создаете БД (которую в любом случае надо хранить на сервере) и пишете хоть Windows приложение, хоть веб.

Comment: ну а как раздать роли в приложении?

Comment: Как вариант: создаете ASP.Net приложение на базе его membership-провайдера (пользователи + роли), а Windows в приложении используете этих же пользователей и роли.

Comment: а как их перенести в win forms приложение не совсем понятно!)https://new.vk.com/urazbahtini если можно то тут посоветуйте)) тут не удобно общаться!

Comment: А если попробовать из ASP перенести подключаемую эту библиотеку в WinForms копи пастом?)))

Comment: Я уже тоже думаю с начало делать ASP .Net приложение

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из комментариев, Вы хотите сделать единую базу пользователей для веб- и для Windows приложения. Варианты реализации могут быть различные: от использования готовых пользовательских провайдеров до написания своих.

Если Вы хотите использовать уже готовые механизмы, могу предложить такой вариант:

1. Вы создаете приложение на ASP.Net и реализуете там стандартный механизм membership-провайдера, который позволяет работать с пользователями, а также с ролями. Примеров реализации можно найти в сети достаточно много. Вот такой простой пример: [Быстрое создание сайта ASP.NET с авторизацией, основанной на формах с использованием стандартного провайдера Membership](http://kooboo-cms.ru/articles/detail/asp-net-site-with-membership-sql-server-2008-visual-studio-2010/)
2. Вы создаете Windows-приложение. Т.к. БД будет уже создана, Вам будет необходимо только подключится к ней, чтобы работать с пользователями. В сети также можно найти примеры по подключению membership-провайдера на WinForms приложениях. Примеры:

   - [Как использовать Membership ASP.NET провайдера в приложении WINFORM](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3855.how-to-use-a-membership-provider-of-asp-net-in-winform-application.aspx)
   - [Использование сервисов ASP.NET в Windows приложении](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/e863aa3c-0dd6-468d-bd35-120a334c5030.aspx)
   - [ASP.Net провайдер в приложении Windows (VB.Net)](http://blogs.msmvps.com/theproblemsolver/2006/01/12/using-the-asp-net-membership-provider-in-a-windows-forms-application-part-1/)
   - и т.д.

Другой вариант, если в школе используется доменная система (Active Directory), то можно реализовать авторизацию на базе доменов.

Comment: не обязательно строго AD, хотя применительно к .NET это удобно. Подойдет любой LDAP сервер для этих целей, даже без обязательного домена в сети. В нем же можно пользователей на группы разбить, чтобы потом права назначать группе, а не индивидуально.

Comment: Да, можно и так реализовать.